# $push min of a document's own value and a constant value into its field

Tags: mongodb

Imagine a document like this:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  num: 2,
  history: []
}
```

I'm $pushing an object into history and I want it to have its own `num: min(item.num + 1, 8)`. In this case we should end up with something like this:

`history: [ {event: 465, ... , num:3 } ]`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below to achieve what you need.

```
db.getCollection(collectionName).find(filterquery).forEach(function(item) {
     var itemNum = min(item.num + 1, 8);
     item.history = [ {event: 465, ... , num:itemNum } ];
  db.getCollection(collectionName).update({'_id': item._id}, {$set: item});
    });
```

Comment: Are you certain this can't be accomplished in a single query?

Comment: I saw the docs. I didnt find anything like in a single query. You can research more for it.